# Programmatic Access to Clap Derive Arg Attribute Properties

Tags: rust, clap

Given a struct defined as follows:

```rust
use clap::Parser;
use validator::Validate;

#[derive(Parser, Debug, Validate)]
#[command(author="", version="0.0.1", about="Utility to split files", long_about = None)]
pub struct TestArgs {

    #[arg(short, long, required = true, help="Specify a local file or folder for processing.\nFolders will attempt to process all files in the folder")]
    #[validate(custom = "crate::cli::validation::validate_input")]
    pub input: String,

    #[arg(short, long, help="This is the location to which processed files are moved.\nDefault value \"\" will be processed as [PWD]/output.", required = false, default_value="")]
    #[validate(custom = "crate::cli::validation::validate_outfolder")]
    pub out_folder: String
}
```

Which is then parsed in main as follows:

```rust
#[tokio::main]
async fn main() -> Result<(), Box<dyn std::error::Error>> {

    let args = TestArgs::parse();

    match args.validate() {
        Ok(_) => (),
        Err(e) => {
            println!();
            eprintln!("{}", e.to_string());
            println!();
            process::exit(1);
        }
    };
.
.
}
```

How can the individual properties values declared in the `arg[]` attribute be programmatically accessed for each argument?

I've found some examples using `clap::Clap` to do something like:

```rust
let arg_parser = TestArgs.into_app();
```

and then access through the `arg_parser` variable.  However, that doesn't seem to be something that is supported in `Clap 4.2.1`.

If someone knows how or has an idea of how to access those values, it would be extremely helpful.

Answer (score 1):

You can access the [`Command`](https://docs.rs/clap/4.2.2/clap/struct.Command.html) generated from your attributes by calling `command()` provided by the [`CommandFactory`](https://docs.rs/clap/4.2.2/clap/trait.CommandFactory.html) trait:

```
use clap::{CommandFactory, Parser};

#[derive(Parser, Debug)]
#[command(author="", version="0.0.1", about="Utility to split files", long_about = None)]
pub struct TestArgs {
    #[arg(short, long, required = true, help="Specify a local file or folder for processing.\nFolders will attempt to process all files in the folder")]
    pub input: String,

    #[arg(short, long, help="This is the location to which processed files are moved.\nDefault value \"\" will be processed as [PWD]/output.", required = false, default_value="")]
    pub out_folder: String
}

fn main() {
    let command = TestArgs::command();
}
```

You can then access everything via the various `get_*`, `is_*`, and other methods on the `Command` and its `Arg`s.

Comment: Thanks @kmdreko!  I'll take a look at that today. I'm new to Rust and Clap.  So, I have a learning to do on everything, but I'm especially trying to get a fluid understanding of the various ways to use Clap.  I haven't done anything with the `get_*` and `is_*` methods yet and I'll give that a go.